# What is the advantage of having a release candidate branch in bitbucket

Tags: branch, bitbucket

We occupy dev, test and master branches. Thinking of branching a new RC in order to cater bug fixes found in the testing phase, as the dev branch would be busy accompanying feature development. Is this a best practice? Or Should I rely on test branch only in order to avoid unnecessary workarounds.